# Increase Maximum Room Occupants count smack api

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

How to increase the deafult maximum room occupants count '30' to a desired count. Is it possible by smack api?

So far I researched, `submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_maxusers", 20000);` is not working as it thorws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  since its type is 'list-single'

How to set value to muc#roomconfig_maxusers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put link to the API, about which you are talking

Comment: http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/3.2.2/documentation/extensions/muc.html - @Gaurava Agarwal

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by giving the maximum users count in arraylist as follows,

```
 ArrayList oArrayList = new ArrayList();
 oArrayList.add("0")
 submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_maxusers", oArrayList);
```